# How to use Facebook and Flickr in one application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use Facebook sdk for Facebook and Objective Flickr for Flickr, but issue is in info property list for URL types. How to add both URL in one list and redirect it to the service that want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add all item to plist normal.

In source code it like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb925133124245003</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>flickrkitdemo</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.devedup.flickrkit</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

With property list:
   [image]

And in `AppDelegate` you need modify `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` . If you have already add facebook it will like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
}
```

So You should modify to:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"yourScheme"]) {
    //Do you need here
        return YES;
   }
   return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
}
```

Hope this help!